# Disabling dock icon for an app in Mac OSX in different way

Tags: macos, hide, dock

In mac osx for most of the applications keeps a dock icon.
But if the developer of the same applications wants to hide the dock icon, then how do he hide it?

As a developer i know '**Info.plist**' property file is one way to hide the dock icon for an application.

But **dont we have any other solution for this?**

I hope there should be some other ways as everybody know "there are N no of way of solutions for a problem"

Thanks in advance

M@k4mac

Comment: Why should you as the application developer be able to control the user's dock?

Comment: @Cody Gray: Some applications are designed to run in the background and not display their icons in the Dock.

Comment: @mipadi: Ah, I meant other than through the `Info.plist`, which is specifically intended to address that use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing the app, you want to set LSUIElement to TRUE in your Info.plist.

If you're *running* the app, you can use a program like [Dockless](http://homepage.mac.com/fahrenba/programs/dockless/dockless.html).

If you want superfluous options, use Linux :)

Answer (score 1):

The Info.plist solution is the only way to hide the icon from the Dock (for a GUI application).

What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's a solution that can be worked out if you give more details.

Answer (score 1):

this LSUIElement method is no longer work under 10.8

add Carbon.framework
make plist Application is agent (UIElement) =1 checked

```
// this should be called from awakeFromNib method
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LaunchAsAgentApp"]) 
{   ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess };

// display dock icon
TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);

// enable menu bar
SetSystemUIMode(kUIModeNormal, 0);

// switch to Dock.app
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.dock"    options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil launchIdentifier:nil];

// switch back
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:TRUE];

}
```